# DSE 6.7 - Error With DSE Driver When SOLR is Enabled

Tags: graph, cassandra, datastax, gremlin

I'm currently working through getting an old project up and running again - it uses both DSE Search and DSE Graph. I don't have too much experience with DSE, but right now I've created one keyspace for the regular cassandra db (searchable) and I've created a graph on the same server using the gremlin console.

The back-end is written in node.js and uses the dse-driver to get data from the DSE server.

When I run the cassandra server with the -g flag, the dse-driver runs fine, does exactly what I want it to do, but obviously, none of my search functionality works.

When I run the cassandra server with the `-g` and `-s` flags, my search functionality works, but then I receive errors whenever the backend tries to use the dse-driver to get data from the graph using the `executeGraph` function.

Is this something that can be fixed or do I need to create more nodes/clusters? I'm really new to DSE so your help is appreciated.

`Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:\n\n1) Error injecting constructor, com.datastax.bdp.gcore.datastore.DataStoreException: Failed to execute statement40f07a96-98bf-490c-a738-6c9d0021afba\n  at com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.DseGraphImpl.<init>(DseGraphImpl.java:192)\n  at com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.GraphModule.configure(Unknown Source) (via modules: com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.DseGraphFactoryImpl$$Lambda$1580/1437671705 -> com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.GraphModule)\n  while locating com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.DseGraphImpl\n\n1 error\n`

Comment: I've used datastax for multiple years now. Have used it with and without SOLR. Have not used GRAPH. However, that being said, the way I've enabled these components before is by modifying the /etc/default/dse file (if you have the tar-ball, it's under the install directory somewhere). In that file, to enable/disable SOLR, GRAPH, SPARK, etc - you simply adjust the XXXXX_ENABLED to 1 (e.g. SOLR_ENABLED=1). Could it be you're not doing that, which may be causing issues?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I modified the dse.default file to have both graph and solr enabled, unfortunately the error still persists.

Comment: What OS, how did you install DSE (package or tarball)? You don't combine flags into something like `-gs`? What query are you trying to execute?

Comment: Linux (Ubuntu), tarball. Combining the flags gives the same result. Most of the queries are g.V().has.....etc etc. Even trying to execute g.V() in the gremlin console raises the error